# Possible to automatically add multiple checkboxes to Excel from SQL Query?

Tags: sql, excel, checkbox

I have the following data in a view that is output to an Excel sheet via a query.

| Verified | Deleted | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | Sean Hull |
| 1 | 0 | Bonnie Davis |
| 0 | 0 | John Smith |
| 0 | 1 | Evel Knieval |
| 1 | 1 | Bart Simpson |
| 0 | 0 | Peter Griffin |

Ideally the first two columns would convert to checkboxes with 1 = Checked, and 0 = Unchecked, but I'm fairly certain that is not possible.
I have added two columns to the right the table so the sheet looks something like this.

| Verified | Deleted | Verified | Deleted | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | 0 | 0 | Sean Hull |
|  |  | 1 | 0 | Bonnie Davis |
|  |  | 0 | 0 | John Smith |
|  |  | 0 | 1 | Evel Knieval |
|  |  | 1 | 1 | Bart Simpson |
|  |  | 0 | 0 | Peter Griffin |

I know I can add a Checkbox via the Developer area, however I have to then manually format the control to set the Cell Link.

Is it possible to automatically create a linked Checkbox?  I don't think I can avoid having to edit the sheet to add the additional columns, but if the checkboxes could be created in some kind of automated way, that would be a huge help as I have a couple views with a couple thousand rows, and manually linking each one isn't really an option.

Comment: hope [this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2689-excel-link-checkbox-to-multiple-cells.html#a2) helps..

Answer (score 0):

After much research this is the only way I found to do what I want.

Create a VB Macro:

```
Sub InsertCheckboxes()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim lCol As Long

    For Each c In Selection
        Dim cb As CheckBox
        Set cb = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(c.Left, _
                                    c.Top, _
                                    c.Width, _
                                    c.Height)
        With cb
            .Caption = ""
            .Value = xlOff
            .LinkedCell = c.Address
            .Display3DShading = False
            .LinkedCell = .TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 2).Address
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```